# What are the differences between WebAPI and WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

What are the MAIN differences (things I should be concerned about) between WepApi and WepApi2 that now ships with Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 57):

Major new features are,

> 1. AttributeRouting
> 2. OWIN self host
> 3. IHttpActionResult
> 4. CORS
> 5. HttpRequestContext

I had the same question and found simple article about this, [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/10/asp-net-web-api-2-is-out-overview-of-features/).

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the features mentioned by [iJay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29790819/685)

6. Testability
7. ODATA Improvements
8. Filter Overrides
9. ByteRangeStreamContent

We can differentiate web api and web api2 by using above features.

Answer (score 11):

WebAPI and WebAPI 2

Actually WebAPI 2.0 is enhanced feature of WebApi there is no difference between this two. 
In version 2.0, the Web API framework has been enhanced to support the following features:

- IHttpActionResult return type
- A new Routing Attribute
- Support for Cross-Origin requests using CORS
- Securing ASP.NET Web API using OAuth 2.0
- Support for $expand, $select in OData Service